# How do I use the 'concat' type in the addColumn() method when building a grid?

Tags: magento, grid, magento-1.7, concatenation, adminhtml

Mage/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Concat.php -- can someone please provide an example of its usage? For instance, can it be used in place of:

```
$this->addColumn('order_item', array(
  'header'=> $this->__('Order # (Item #)'),
  'sortable'=> true,
  'index'=> 'order_item',
  'filter_index'=> "CONCAT(orders.increment_id, ' (', main_table.item_id, ')')",
  'width'=> '140px',
));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks Simon! The addColumn renderers are cased out in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column::_getRendererByType() so it is not necessary to manually add it although that is very cool to know. I still had issues if I left off the filter index, but I did clean up the code to this:

```
$this->addColumn('order_item', 
    array(
        'header'       => $this->__('Order # -- Item #'),
        'sortable'     => true,
        'index'        => array('increment_id', 'item_id'),
        'type'         => 'concat',
        'separator'    => ' -- ',
        'filter_index' => "CONCAT(orders.increment_id, ' -- ', main_table.item_id)",
        'width'        => '140px',
    )
);
```

Comment: Nice to know, too. Thought `type` was a reference to the table column type but it makes perfect sense. Please mark your question as solved.

Comment: Beneath the Up/Down voting arrow of your answer should be a checkmark.

Comment: filter is not working, it gives error "Unknown column 'concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)' in 'where clause'". Please help me to resolve that error. - @monkeygod

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be used like every renderer in `renderer`. The columns to be concatenated can be set in an array in `index`. I think it's not possible to use `separators` like you want to. It tested in product grid:

```
  $this->addColumn('entity_id',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
            'index' => array('entity_id','sku'),
            'separator'=>'|',
            'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_concat',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can merge two columns in Grid using below method.

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('customreport')->__('Name'),
            'sortable'  =>true,
            'index'     =>array('firstname', 'lastname'),
            'type'      =>'concat',
            'separator' =>' '
        ));
```

Comment: You miss the `filter_index`, so its not possible to filter this column.

Comment: Yes to filter the column need to add filter_index. I used it for display purpose only.